# CocoaAsyncSocket server won't start if called from another class

Tags: objective-c, swift, sockets, cocoaasyncsocket

It's a simple socket server.

If I remove `Socket` class and put `serverSocket` variable and `startSocketServer` function inside the `ViewController` class Socket server will be started to listening.

I check by `lsof -i :6000` command to determine if socket started to listening or not.

Whats wrong?!

```
import UIKit
import CocoaAsyncSocket

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let server = Socket()
        server.startSocketServer()
    }
}

class Socket: NSObject, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate {
    var serverSocket = GCDAsyncSocket()

    /// Staring socket server
    func startSocketServer() {
        self.serverSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        do {
             try serverSocket.acceptOnInterface(nil, port: 6000)
        } catch {
            print("Port access failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I Put the Socket class definition: `let server = Socket()` out of `viewDidLoad` function fixed my issue.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let server = Socket()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        server.startSocketServer()
    }
}
```